# build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, build-impl.xml

I've a problem on Netbeans, after any sucessfully deploys, they show me this msg:

build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.

I'been restart netbeans any times and change debugmode to TRUE but the problem continue.

It's the line 1045 by build-impl.xml:

```
1044 <target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
1045        <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="true" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
1046    </target>
```

Help me, Thanks!!

Comment: Problem resolved, i included a servlet-mapping in WEB.XML but don't included the servelet-class reference.

Answer (score 0):

This could also happen if you do not properly configure servlets in deployment descriptor

Example: notice servlet names are different

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>abcd</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>xxx</servlet-class>
</servlet> 

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xxx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```